# How can I call Artisan::call(...) more than once? (Migrate and then Seed)

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-seeding

I have found that using the `Artisan::call()` command to migrate and then again to seed results in a proper migration but the database is never seeded. This may be a bug or perhaps there is a way to flush the previous command.

For example:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', [
    '--database'  => 'tenant',
    '--path'      => 'database/tenantMigrations',
    '--force'     => true,
]);
```

And then:

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', [
    '--database'  => 'tenant',
    '--class' => 'TenantSeeder',
]);
```

As you can see, I am running these commands on a freshly created tenant DB to "provision" it. Each of these commands works separately, but not together.

I have tried looking for further documentation on joining the two commands while being able to specify the class of the seeder. This would potentially look like:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', [
    '--database'  => 'tenant',
    '--path'      => 'database/tenantMigrations',
    '--force'     => true,
    '--seed'      => true,
    '--class'     => 'TenantSeeder', // this is the only one I can't do, which is critical
]);
```

I have also tried running the seeder like:

```
(new \TenantSeeder)->run();
```

I get the error: `Call to a member function line() on null`.

It is also interesting to note that all works properly on my local Homestead environment, but not on a Digital Ocean server managed by Forge.

#### Edit

My current solution is to put my seeder logic inside of regular classes (that do not extend the base Seeder class) and call these as I displayed above.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a wrapper command with all the options needed, then call the `migrate`, `seed`, etc commands individually:

```
php artisan make:command MigrateAndSeedCommand
```

The class may look something like:

```
class MigrateAndSeedCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'migrateandseed {--database=} {--path=} {--force} {--seed} {--class=}';

    public function handle()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate', [
            '--database'  => $this->option('database'),
            '--path'      => $this->option('path'),
            '--force'     => $this->option('force'),
        ]);
        Artisan::call('db:seed', [
            '--database'  => $this->option('database'),
            '--class'     => $this->option('class'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Usable via:

```
php artisan migrateandseed --database=tenants --path=database/tenantMigrations --force --seed --class=TenantSeeder

// or 

Artisan::call('migrateandseed', [
    '--database'  => 'tenant',
    '--path'      => 'database/tenantMigrations',
    '--force'     => true,
    '--seed'      => true,
    '--class'     => 'TenantSeeder',
]);
```

**EDIT**

Use `$this` instead of `Artisan`, as well as optionally queueing the commands:

```
// or  $this->queue
$this->call('db:seed', [
    '--database'  => $this->option('database'),
    '--class'     => $this->option('class'),
]);
```

[Calling Commands From Other Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands)

Comment: The problem is, two Artisan commands cannot be run. The second one is skipped. (see the original post)

Comment: See my update, don't use the `Artsian` facade, instead use `$this`